# C++ wrapper library: Allocate C++ object in C on the stack

Tags: c++, c

I've created a library in C++, exposing some C++ objects.
Since the library should be usable in other languages than C++, (C, and through FFI, Java and Python), I have created a small wrapper library, like that:

```
    typedef void* MyObject;    
    MyObject create_Object(); // implemented in C++, returns a C++ Object as void*, allocated on the heap
    doSomething(MyObject);
    deleteObject(MyObject);
```

So far, so good. That's all pretty standard, but I do not like the overhead of allocating the object on the heap, moreover, I want to eliminate the possible error of not calling the free method deleteObject. 
So, I though of something like that:

```
    // somehow tell C that MyObject consists of X bytes
    MyObject my; // I can allocate this now on the stack, since C knows its size
    create_object(&my); // allocates it
    doSometing(&my);
    // no need to free, so destructor is not called (there is no real need to call it anymway)
```

Is something like that possible?
Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that once the library returns an object to the application there is no way of knowing when the application is finished with it, and it's safe to delete. So the easiest way is to invent some kind of protocol. There has been a lot of work in this area, smart pointers, reference counting etc, but in my experience these are not as easy to implement as they first appear.

If you are worried about memory leaks, providing a library function to delete the object will allow you to track what was allocated against what was freed and you can log some kind of error message, but typically this only happens once your library is unloaded.

If you don't want the performance overhead allocating objects on the heap, with a delete function you could implement some kind of caching mechanism where create only creates an object if there are none in the cache.

Comment: Well, in both cases, the user would have to free the object manually in order to deconstruct it (using the deleteMyObject method). But in the second case on the stack, the C wrapper can at least unallocate the memory (but the deconstructor is not called). That's at least something.
I really appreciate the pointer you gave me (tracking allocations), but due to overhead, that's not an option

Comment: If you allocate the object on the create functions stack, it will be invalid as soon as that method ends, you have no choice but to dynamically allocate the space. Otherwise you have to just return the values and let the client copy the values into an application created object.

Comment: I am not allocated it in the functions stack.
When calling MyObject my; i would like to allocate e.g. 20 bytes on the stack.
The initialiser new_MyObject just calls the C++ constructor (sets the instance variables, ...)